# Call custom JS function from PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have enqueued external JS file for some of my WP Theme functions.  I can call these functions by its name on buttons without problem. Now, I need to call one function based on custom WP_Query condition result. I have find that if I use `<script>` tags this code is working

```
<header class="page-header">
            <?php
            $allsearch = new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=0");
            $asfp = $allsearch->found_posts;?>
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo $asfp ?><?php printf( esc_html__( ' posts for: %s', 'webovkar' ),
                    '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
            <?php if($asfp < 1) :?>

               <script>
                   (function searchAgain(){
                       var e = document.querySelector('#search-section').classList;
                       e.add("visible");
                   }());
               </script>

            <?php  endif; ?>

        </header><!-- .page-header-->
```

My question is: Is there better (cleaner) way just to call function by its name `searchAgain();` from external JS file as on buttons instead injecting function as it is now ?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: As I wrote in first line of my request I have this function in external JS file that is enqueued and other functions in this file are working if I trigger them with button but when I called this specific function by its name ```searchAgain();``` it didn't find it and result was undefined function in this code and in external js file name function was grey (not used). Thats why I have injected function into code but I don't like it and I'm looking for better solution.

Comment: This is my enqueued file where was originally my function `wp_enqueue_script( 'main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/webovkar.js', '', '20151215', true );`

Comment: You can use a global variable then. Use something like `var searchAgain = true;` inside your conditional, and then check for its `true/false` in your enqueued JS file.

Comment: I can't make it work, can you post simple example? Thanks